# Objectify: Filter by an attribute of collection entries?

Tags: google-app-engine, collections, objectify

I'm using Objectify on Google's AppEngine.
I have the following Entity-Model:

```
@Entity
public class ChallengeEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Index
    public List<ChallengeParticipant> participants;
}
```

The Participant (not an entity... should it be one?)

```
public class ChallengeParticipant {
    @Load
    public Ref<UserEntity> user;

    // ... participant-specific attributes
}
```

And the User-Entity:

```
@Entity
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Index
    public String email = "";
}
```

**Now how would I find all challenges for a given user-email?**
Something along:

```
ofy().load().type(ChallengeEntity.class).filter("participants.user.email", "test@local.foo")
```

I am willing to adapt my entity-model to GAE's needs... how may I support this query *efficiently* and keep a nice model?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your list of `ChallengeParticipant` is reasonably bounded (a few hundred at most) and you aren't at risk of hitting the 1M per-entity size limit, you're probably best leaving it as embedded.

To perform your query, first lookup the person by email, then filter by person:

```
UserEntity user = // load user (or get the key) by email
ofy().load().type(ChallengeEntity.class).filter("participants.user", user);
```

Note that you need to `@Index` the `ChallengeParticipant.user` field, not the `ChallengeEntity.participants` list.

Comment: thanks for mentioning to `@Index` the user instead of the participants... but why?

Comment: `@Index` on the collection means "index all the fields of every item in this collection". You only want to index the one field.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that email is unique for a user, I'd keep `ChallengeParticipant` as a separate entity and maintain 2 way relationship with `ChallangeEntity`:

```
public class ChallengeParticipant {
    @Id
    String email; // must be able to uniquely identify a user. 
    List<Ref<ChallengeEntity>> challenges;
    // ... participant-specific attributes
}
```

ChallengeEntity will exist as is but without any @Index

```
@Entity
public class ChallengeEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    public List<Ref<ChallengeParticipant>> participants;
}
```

When you want to add a new participant to a challenge, update both entities (Participant & Challenge) in one transaction. As there are no indexes involved, you'll always get consistent results.